# Can there be more than one largest normal subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Is it possible for a group $\mathcal{G}$ to have normal subgroups $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$, such that $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ have the same order and are both the largest, but their elements are all different except $e$?

If this is true, would the decomposition of a group in terms of its largest normal subgroup still be unique?

Comment: Perhaps "maximal so and so subgroups" is better than "the largest", as this usually includes the idea of *unique* (there are precise names in partial orders and etc. for these things...)

Comment: I checked also for $\mathcal{Q}$, all its order 4 subgroups are normal, which are also the largest. There are then three different ways to composite $\mathcal{Q}$.

Comment: By $\mathcal{Q}$ I mean the quaternion group of rank 2.

Answer (score 3):

What about $\;\{1\}\times C_p\;,\;\;C_p\times\{1\}\;$ in $\;C_p\times C_p\;$ ,with $\;C_p:=$ the (one and unique up to isomorphism) *cyclic* group of order a prime $\;p\;$

Comment: Moreover, any example looks like this: the direct product of simple groups.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good example. Are there any groups that could be decomposed differently?